# Catch the "Data range is too complex" error in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

In an excel macro I'm working on I copy filtered data to a new sheet to remove the hidden rows. This allows me to run more complex formulas on the data that the user has filtered. With large data sets that were complex-ly filtered the copy operation no longer took only filtered data but copied ALL data over.

When replicating the procedure manually Excel gave me the "data range is too complex" error when I attempted to copy the filtered data. This is easy enough to get past by sorting and then filtering, however I can't figure out how to catch this error in VBA. I'd like a way to know if the copy operation is working properly (and allow the macro to continue) or if the selection is too complex (and stop the macro and alert the user to try sorting first).

Any idea how I can do this? Any help would be appreciated.

Relevant code below:

```
    Select Case Range("GDT_Filtered").Value
    Case "Filtered Data"
        Worksheets.Add after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
        Set wRaw = ActiveSheet
        Sheets("Raw Data").Select
        lastRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
        Range("A1:S" & lastRow).Copy Destination:=wRaw.Range("A1")

    Case "All Data"
        Set wRaw = Sheets("Raw Data")
        On Error Resume Next
        wRaw.ShowAllData
        On Error GoTo 0
    End Select
```

Thanks!

Sam

Comment: it is rather common error but would be easier to answer if you show us part of your code where the exception occurs.

Comment: @KazJaw the code that creates the problem is: `Range("A1:S" & LastRow).Copy Destination:=wRaw.Range("A1")`. The range it's copying is filtered. And again, it _doesn't_ throw an exception, which is the problem.

Comment: I think I know what to suggest but please, add some more of your code to your question where you show us `LastRow` definition and `wRaw`, too. Than I'll try to answer...

Comment: @KazJaw Thanks! The code sections have been added to the question - let me know if you need to see anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I've figured out a manageable work-around.

Assuming the original data is stored in sheet wOne, and the filtered data is copied to sheet wTwo, the following code will find the error by checking for filtering and the number of rows in each sheet:

```
' Excel can't copy too many discontinuous sections. If it happens it won't throw
' an error but will copy ALL data instead of just filtered data. This checks that
' such an error has not occurred.
If wOne.AutoFilter.FilterMode = True Then
    If wOne.range("A1").End(xlDown).Row = wTwo.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row Then
        MsgBox "Filtering has produced too many discontinuous selections. " & _ 
                "Try removing the filters, sorting data by the variables " & _ 
                "you wish to filter with, reapplying the filters, and " & _
                "trying again. Good luck!"
        GoTo 1
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Use OnError

```
sub 

   On Error Goto 1

   do the copy, if it fails, code will jump to 1.

   On Error Goto 0 'zero means you are not doing any treatment for further errors

   continue the code

   exit sub 'you don't want the code to do error treatment below if there's no error

   1 Do what you need if error occurs

end sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Unfortunately this operation doesn't throw an error at all - when doing it manually excel will pop up an alert saying _"Microsoft Office Excel cannot create or use the data range reference because it is too complex"_ but then will go ahead and copy **all** the data, not just the filtered data. In VBA it doesn't register as an error and doesn't pop up an alert, it just continues on with the full copy.